# Background Image Doesnt Show When Right To Left Is True

Tags: c#, winforms, background-image

In Windows Form When

```
RightToLeft=yes
```

and

```
RightToLeftLayout=true
```

i can not

set any background image for my form!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [MSDN entry for the `Form.RightToLeftLayout` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.righttoleftlayout.aspx):

> Owner draw is not supported when `RightToLeftLayout` is set to Yes. The owner draw events will still occur, but the behavior of any code you author in these events is not defined. Additionally, `BackgroundImage`, `Opacity`, `TransparencyKey`, and the painting events are not supported.

Answer (score 2):

According to Prshanth's answer, you need to handle the background painting yourself.

Microsoft wasn't lazy, they simply didn't know what you want to be happening  when the reading layout of the form is changed.
Perhaps you want your background image to be flipped? They just don't know, so instead of doing something wrong, they did nothing.

The good thing is that you can simply do it yourself like this.
In this example, I simply store the desired background image in a PictureBox and then paint it onto the form when the Form.Paint event occurs:

```
Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint

    Dim r As Rectangle = Me.ClientRectangle
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(Me.PictureBox1.BackgroundImage, r)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

add a PictureBox and dock it to fill the form and you’ll get a background

Comment: This will make any container controls lose it's backcolor transparency. This means that another picturebox on the picturebox will not be transparent. I think labels won't be transparent as well. Therefore I have added the answer below.