# Hidden background image C# winform in right to left layout?

Tags: c#, winforms

I set background image to form in my project C# winform, but when set Form property to

```
RightToLeft=Yes  and  RightToLeftLayout=True
```

then disappear my background image.
Does anyone help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Background Image Doesnt Show When Right To Left Is True](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10764300/background-image-doesnt-show-when-right-to-left-is-true)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can paint the image manually, by overriding the `OnPaintBackground` method of your form:

```
protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
{  
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(Properties.Resources.SampleImage,
                         new Rectangle(Point.Empty, this.ClientSize));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By using background image, you have to know that it is not supported by `RightToLeftLayout` so you cannot use it directly in this case, but that doesn't mean that you can't implement it manually.

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.righttoleftlayout.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Owner draw is not supported when RightToLeftLayout is set to Yes. The owner draw events will still occur, but the behavior of any code you author in these events is not defined. Additionally, BackgroundImage, Opacity, TransparencyKey, and the painting events are not supported.

Referece:

[[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.righttoleftlayout(v=vs.110).aspx][1]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.righttoleftlayout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx%5d%5b1%5d)

Answer (score 0):

Look this:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=ZH-CN&k=k(System.Windows.Forms.Form.RightToLeftLayout)%3bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2cVersion%3dv4.5)%3bk(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=ZH-CN&k=k%28System.Windows.Forms.Form.RightToLeftLayout%29%3bk%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2cVersion%3dv4.5%29%3bk%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true)

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backgroundimage(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backgroundimage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If you set RightToLeftLayout=True ,you'll not use backgroundimage.